# Mysql Error Output: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql, row

SQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO probid_users 
(username, password, email, reg_date, payment_mode, balance, max_credit, salt, tax_account_type, tax_company_name, tax_reg_number, tax_apply_exempt, name, address, city, country, state, zip_code, phone, birthdate, birthdate_year, newsletter, pg_paypal_email, pg_worldpay_id, pg_checkout_id, pg_nochex_email, pg_ikobo_username, pg_ikobo_password, pg_protx_username, pg_protx_password, pg_authnet_username, pg_authnet_password, pg_mb_email, pg_paymate_merchant_id, pg_gc_merchant_id, pg_gc_merchant_key, pg_amazon_access_key, pg_amazon_secret_key, pg_alertpay_id, pg_alertpay_securitycode, pg_gunpal_id, first_name, last_name, pg_account_number, pg_account_holder_name, pg_account_holders_number, pg_bank_name, pg_bank_code, pg_paypal_percent_fee, pg_paypal_flat_fee ) 
VALUES 
('42685', '**181e6bd87b116b270bef7c308fd2afdb**', 'jose_jamo@hotmail.com', **1368979346**, **2**, '-5', '5.00', 'dc1', '0', '', '', '0', 'vv fvf', 'fvfvf', 'fvfv', '2083', '2173', '4262', '28823625', '1986-01-01', '1986', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'vv', 'fvf', '', '','', '', '')
```

Where is the error?  Is between **????***?

Comment: it sounds like you have too many or too little values, have you cross counted?

Answer (score 1):

Your "INSERT INTO" part of your query specifies 50 columns but your "VALUES" only specifies 48.  You could add two more blank string values to even it out.

```
INSERT INTO probid_users (username, password, email, reg_date, payment_mode, balance, max_credit, salt, tax_account_type, tax_company_name, tax_reg_number, tax_apply_exempt, name, address, city, country, state, zip_code, phone, birthdate, birthdate_year, newsletter, pg_paypal_email, pg_worldpay_id, pg_checkout_id, pg_nochex_email, pg_ikobo_username, pg_ikobo_password, pg_protx_username, pg_protx_password, pg_authnet_username, pg_authnet_password, pg_mb_email, pg_paymate_merchant_id, pg_gc_merchant_id, pg_gc_merchant_key, pg_amazon_access_key, pg_amazon_secret_key, pg_alertpay_id, pg_alertpay_securitycode, pg_gunpal_id, first_name, last_name, pg_account_number, pg_account_holder_name, pg_account_holders_number, pg_bank_name, pg_bank_code, pg_paypal_percent_fee, pg_paypal_flat_fee ) 
VALUES ('42685', '181e6bd87b116b270bef7c308fd2afdb', 'jose_jamo@hotmail.com', 1368979346, 2, '-5', '5.00', 'dc1', '0', '', '', '0', 'vv fvf', 'fvfvf', 'fvfv', '2083', '2173', '4262', '28823625', '1986-01-01', '1986', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'vv', 'fvf', '', '','', '', '', '', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to count all of those fields to make sure they're, but the problem might be that '' in SQL is a way to escape '. Instead of using '' for an empty string, try \'\' or '''' . Confusing, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Your column count doesn't match your value count.

To prevent this in the future:

If there is the possibility that there is no value (probably all fields with an empty string '' in your query), you should add the option that a certain column can be `NULL`.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
    field1 int NULL /* INSTEAD OF NOT NULL */
)
```

Null means you don't know the value yet or there is no value. Then you would be able to execute a statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO probid_users 
(username, password, email, reg_date, payment_mode, balance, max_credit, salt, tax_account_type, tax_apply_exempt, name, address, city, country, state, zip_code, phone, birthdate, birthdate_year, newsletter, pg_paypal_email, pg_account_number, pg_account_holder_name) 
VALUES 
('42685', '**181e6bd87b116b270bef7c308fd2afdb**', 'jose_jamo@hotmail.com', **1368979346**, **2**, '-5', '5.00', 'dc1', '0', '', '', '0', 'vv fvf', 'fvfvf', 'fvfv', '2083', '2173', '4262', '28823625', '1986-01-01', '1986', 'vv', 'fvf')
```

If you only insert available and not all values, you can prevent mistakes like this in the future.

BTW: You should also take a look at database normalization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)